# How to override library's png drawable by app's vector drawable (xml)?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I am using a Library in my Android Project. The Library has `ic_sample.png` in `drawable/` (hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxhdpi) directories. I want to replace that icon with my own icon.

### Option 1 (using Multiple pngs):

**works but not a clean solution for almost 2020**

- Take my own icon's png file and rename it to `ic_sample.png`
- Put it under all drawable dirs `drawable/` +(hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxhdpi).

### Option 2 (using single Vector drawable):

**that's the question**
- Override library's icons by a vector drawable xml.